# Is there any way to repair files corrupted by not properly closing boost::archive::binary_oarchive?

Tags: c++, boost, binaryfiles

I ran a large processing job which produced lots of binary files as output.  I think I realize now that my output data files got corrupted because I did not properly flush or close the `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` object before moving the data files to remote storage.  I'm wondering if there is any way to repair the output data files by appending them with some special EOF thing, or whether I'm out of luck and I have to re-run the expensive job?

More specifically, my processing job dumps the binary data like so:

```
   void dumpStuff() {
        // some code
        std::ofstream ofs(localFileName);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive boa(ofs);
        boa << *data;   

        if (uploadToRemote) {
            // code that uploads files to remote store
            // does not run when I tested locally
        }
    }
```

What I think happens is that when I tested locally (and did not upload to remote), the `boa` object goes out of scope at the end of the `dumpStuff` function and so it's destructor gets called, which properly flushes the stream and closes the file.  When uploading to remote store, however, the upload happens before the `oba`'s destructor is called, so it is my belief that the stream was not properly flushed, resulting in a corrupt file.  When I fetch the corrupted file from the store and attempt to load with `boost::archive::binary_iarchive`, I get an `InputStreamError`.

I know I can fix the problem by adding some braces around the `boa` stuff to force it to go out of scope before uploading to remote, however, this will only solve my problem if I re-run the big expensive job.  So, my question is, is there some simple way to just append something to the end of my corrupt files to de-corrupt them?  Some kind of EOF signal?

Comment: I'd probably weigh any development expense against re-running the large job. In most cases, re-running it will end up cheaper. And in any case more predictable. You already lost 8 hours since posting this question on SO (assuming you didn't start the re-run)

Comment: This is a long shot. You can modify the top level of the deserialization routine (usually called `load`) to detect an inconsistent value (e.g. a very large integer) and stop the deserialization there. You will end up with a value in some invalid state but it could be that you have 99% of the information you want to recover.

Comment: "Is there any way to repair files corrupted by not properly closing" No. "... boost::archive::binary_oarchive?" Irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be. Then again most of it will surely depend on the flushing behaviour of the underlying stream you used.

This is a one-off problem that only you have, so you will have to make a solution.

- One way would be to look at the source code to figure out exactly what actions would be skipped due to the missing close. And then either compensate the missing input OR make the input-archive implementation more tolerant for corrupt/missing tails.
- The other approach would be to use your own code WITH the flaw to write an archive, and then write the SAME archive but with the error fixed.

  Just look at the difference in a hex editor. You may be lucky and find that the data missing from the archive is fixed. If so, just append it to any corrupt input stream and be glad. More likely you will have some (simple) variable data, like a checksum or a total size. In that case either try to generate the missing data, or hack the input-stream implementation to detect the required checksum.

> CAVEAT: All of these suggest meddling with undocumented details, there will not be support, reliability depends solely on your own accuracy.
>
> If you choose to "fake" checksums, be aware of the fact that it thwarts any builtin error-detection, so you might still read unreliable data (in case there was data corrupted in sotrage/transit)

Comment: Good thought to generate the diff.  I might try that on a few files to see if there is some pattern, but ultimately I'm leaning towards just biting the bullet and re-running the computation.  Thanks for your response.